# Does embedded Derby database go in Java jar?

Tags: java, mysql, derby

I am working on project in java where I need to have both app as well as Database to be on USB .
I am thinking of either:

1) Installing MySQL on USB. But then I don't know how I would connect to my database that way. I also don't know how I would transfer the project from my development environment to client environment.

OR

2) Using embedded database like derby. I would package my app in jar and give it to the client. He could then keep it on USB and run it from their. In this case where would the database be stored? Will it be stored in the jar file? And if so how do I update my database in these scenario? Can I use ij tool from derby?
I am relatively new to derby.

Comment: Do something about the spelling of your question please, it's horrible.  And yes, scenario 2 is perfectly doable, I think storing the db next to the jar, or in some subdir of the directory containing the jar is the best solution.  And why would you need ij?  As some kind of maintenance tool for the database?

Comment: @fvu your comment is the right answer :-)

Comment: @vels4j Glad you agree, I was waiting for Sanket's clarifications re ij

Comment: sorry @fvu i have been away for some work for so long.. I was thinking abt ij so that i can create a dump of my DB and den use ij tool to deploy at at client place. I was thinking it to be somthing like mysql workbench <as pointed to me by my friend>..

Comment: fvu yeah i will try to do somthing abt my spellings..!! ;)
thnx fvu and @vels4j

Comment: @SanketVGarg ij is the maintenance tool that comes with Derby, but it's a whole lot less user friendly than Workbench.  You could try [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), it's also a Java program and has great support for Derby.

Comment: ok thanks @fvu i will read about it and update you guys if I am stuck thanks for your time..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a great introduction to Derby and its features, follow this series of tutorials: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

Comment: thnx a lot @Bryan.. it really helped